# C++ secret message school assignment

Tags: c++

I am working on a school project, in which I'm supposed to take a message or word like nice or {#&@ and convert it to a word using a vector and a loop.  I have the code running but I can't figure out why it doesn't convert. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> normalV(26);
    vector<char> cipherV(26);
    string toDec = "";
    string beenDec = "";

    int i = 0;  // index normalV
    int n = 0; // index cipherV
    i = 0;      
    n = 0;

    normalV.at(i) = 'n'; cipherV.at(n) = '{';
    normalV.at(i) = 'i'; cipherV.at(n) = '#';
    normalV.at(i) = 'c'; cipherV.at(n) = '&';
    normalV.at(i) = 'e'; cipherV.at(n) = '@';


    // Get secret message
    do {
        cout << "Enter a secret message: ";
        getline(cin, toDec);
    } while (toDec.length() == 0);

    beenDec = toDec;

    for (i = 0; i < toDec.size(); ++i) {
        for (n = 0; n < 26; ++n){
            if (toDec.at(i) == cipherV.at(n)){
                beenDec.at(i) = normalV.at(n);
            }
        }
    } 

    cout << "Decrypted message: " << beenDec << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run the code through line by line in a debugger to see what it is doing and why it doesn’t do what you think it should?

Comment: try to debug your do while loop, it'll help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at this part of the code :

```
normalV.at(i) = 'n'; cipherV.at(n) = '{';
normalV.at(i) = 'i'; cipherV.at(n) = '#';
normalV.at(i) = 'c'; cipherV.at(n) = '&';
normalV.at(i) = 'e'; cipherV.at(n) = '@';
```

`i` and `n` never change here. So, you're always overwriting the first entry in those vectors.

Comment: care to explain why this works then.

        normalV.at(0) = 'n'; cipherV.at(0) = '{';
 normalV.at(1) = 'i'; cipherV.at(1) = '#';

Comment: @TRoberts : I'm not sure I understand your question - by doing that, you fixed the first issue pointed out in this answer. Do you understand what the issue is ?

Comment: @TRoberts : note that when I was referring to `i` and `n`, I was referring to the variables of that name (used as indexes into the vectors), *not* the characters placed into one of the vectors.

Comment: The elements aren't uninitialised, they're initialised to `0`

Comment: @AlanBirtles : you're absolutely right - I'll blame that one on the fact it's monday :) Fixed. Thanks !

Comment: Yes thank you for your help.  I was up late (36 hours straight actually) and realize my error.